# Adding an object instance to a CompositeCollection as an item

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, compositecollection

Is there a way to add a single item to the CompositeCollection (used as source for ComboBox) in addition to other sub-collections?

- The object instance of the item is a Property on the ViewModel
- Both the added item and items in other sub-collections are of the
  same type.

Here's what I have:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combo">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionAsAProperty" Source="{Binding CollectionA, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyViewModel.StaticCollection}}" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionAsAProperty}}"/>

   ===> what should I add here to add another item of DataContext.AnotherItem

        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**EDIT**: It worked somewhat with

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{x:Static local:MyViewModel.AnotherItem}"/>
```

But, **(1)** it requires a static property, and **(2)** in the attached command (not shown here for brevity), the type of the selected item that is returned is `ObjectDataProvider`, not the type of `MyViewModel.AnotherItem`, which causes some pain in the ViewModel

Comment: Rather than working around this issue in this way, don't you think it would be easier to just wrap your `AnotherItem` in an `IEnumerable` that `CollectionContainer` can bind to as a `Collection`? That way the two issues you mentioned no longer exist as your property no longer has to be static and also the `DataType` will be of the correct custom type T. As far as the `CompositeCollection` and `CollectionContainer` are concerned, you've given them a new `List` when you're actually only having 1 item in that list(`AnotherItem`) => no functionality hiccups

Comment: @Viv, I did just that to unblock myself from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move the composite collection to your viewModel and add all differing collections using the [Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.add.aspx) in the code behind.

```
    var myAnimals = new List<Animal>() { new Animal() { Name = "Zebra" },
                                         new Animal() { Name = "Cobra" }} ;

    var myPeople = new List<Person>() { new Person() { Name = "Snake Pliskin" },
                                        new Person()  { Name = "OmegaMan" }};


    var FavoriteThings = new CompositeCollection();

    FavoriteThings.Add(myAnimals);
    FavoriteThings.Add(myPeople);
```

---

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```